# PC working and booting very slow

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, bios

Sorry for any lack of details in advance,

- Motherboard - MSI H110 M Pro VH-Plus
- Processor - Intel Pentium G4400 @ 3.30GHz (base)
- RAM - 4GB Crucial DDR4 2400MHz CL17 4gb
- SSD - NA
- HDD - WD 1Tb 7200rpm
- OS - Windows 10 Pro, May 2020 update
- Architecture - 64 bit
- Graphics -integrated Intel 510

I have tried almost everything from fresh install to virtual memory allocation to BIOS configuration but my PC takes at least 1-1.5 mins to boot and load apps etc.
[HDD is in good condition]
Please tell something you think might help.
Thank you in "Advance"

Answer (score 0):

These problems are normally due to the HDD.  Replacing the HDD with an SSD will make a big improvement.   If the HDD is failing (which is consistent with your post) it will make a massive difference.